# Выполнение функции после прокрутки определённого количества пикселей(jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Нужно сделать обработчик события(scroll) на jQuery. Нужно чтобы после прокрутки страницы на определённое количество пикселей выполнялась функция **function handler()**. Какими способами это можно сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При помощи "доп. проверки" можно выполнить любое действие, после определённого кол-ва пикселей, только один раз.

В примере показано использование *после n px* и *до n px*

```js
let isScroll = 0, // доп. проверка
    targetScroll = 100; // расстояние до действия / в px
    
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
  if(isScroll === 0 && $(this).scrollTop() >= targetScroll) {
    isScroll = 1;
    $('.block').css('background', 'red');
    console.info('change 1');
  } else if(isScroll === 1 && $(this).scrollTop() < targetScroll) {
    isScroll = 0;
    $('.block').css('background', 'green');
    console.info('change 0');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: calc(100vh + 500px);
}

.block {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block"> </div>
```

Comment: Отличный способ!)

Answer (score 2):

Действует при прокрутке самой страницы. (Для демонстрации пример скопировать и запустить в у себя.) 
Если необходимо прокрутку элемента - заменить `document.body.scrolltop` на элемент прокрутки.

```js
    window.onscroll = function () { // отслеживаем скролл
        var z = document.body.scrollTop; // Получаем высоту передвигаемого сролла
        var pixels = 300; // Указываем количество пикселей
        if (z > pixels){
            console.log("Прокручено на 200px") // Для демонстрации вывод сообщения. У себя меняете на выполнение Вашей функции.
        }
    }
```

```html
<div>2 раза КУ</div>
<div>2 раза КУ</div>
<div>2 раза КУ</div>
<div>2 раза КУ</div>
<div>2 раза КУ</div>
<div>2 раза КУ</div>
<div>2 раза КУ</div>
<div>2 раза КУ</div>
<div>2 раза КУ</div>
<div>2 раза КУ</div>
<div>2 раза КУ</div>
<div>2 раза КУ</div>
<div>2 раза КУ</div>
<div>2 раза КУ</div>
<div>2 раза КУ</div>
<div>2 раза КУ</div>
<div>2 раза КУ</div>
<div>2 раза КУ</div>
<div>2 раза КУ</div>
<div>2 раза КУ</div>
<div>2 раза КУ</div>
<div>2 раза КУ</div>
<div>2 раза КУ</div>
<div>2 раза КУ</div>
<div>2 раза КУ</div>
<div>2 раза КУ</div>
<div>2 раза КУ</div>
<div>2 раза КУ</div>
<div>2 раза КУ</div>
<div>2 раза КУ</div>
<div>2 раза КУ</div>
<div>2 раза КУ</div>
<div>2 раза КУ</div>
<div>2 раза КУ</div>
<div>2 раза КУ</div>
<div>2 раза КУ</div>
<div>2 раза КУ</div>
<div>2 раза КУ</div>
<div>2 раза КУ</div>
<div>2 раза КУ</div>
<div>2 раза КУ</div>
<div>2 раза КУ</div>
<div>2 раза КУ</div>
<div>2 раза КУ</div>
<div>2 раза КУ</div>
<div>2 раза КУ</div>
<div>2 раза КУ</div>
<div>2 раза КУ</div>
<div>2 раза КУ</div>
<div>2 раза КУ</div>
<div>2 раза КУ</div>
<div>2 раза КУ</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Отслеживаем прокрутку:

```
if ($(selector).scrollTop() > n){

    // вызов нужной функции
    handler();


}
```

n - переменная, определяет вертикальную позицию прокрутки в пикселях

Comment: По сути первый результат гугл поиска: https://basicweb.ru/jquery/jquery_event_scroll.php

Comment: **после определённого количества пикселей**

Comment: @Cobret,  так?)......

Answer (score 1):

Вариант jQuery.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 100) { //прокручиваем страницу вниз на 100px
    $('body').css('background', 'red'); //получаем событие
  } else { //если меньше чем на 100px
    $('body').css('background', 'white'); //возвращаем
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 200vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
крутите
```